# Get dimens of an ImageView inside an adapter for a ListView

Tags: android, image, android-listview, android-adapter

Im trying to resize an image received via the camera, to fit in an ImageView that will be part of a item in a ListView.

So, in my onActivityResult I get the image...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/imageneslpi");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        file = new File(myDir, fname);
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        lat=Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong("latitud", 0));
        lon=Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong("longitud", 0));

        try {
            ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(file.getCanonicalPath());
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, convert(lat));
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, convert(lon));
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, latitudeRef(lat));
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, longitudeRef(lon));
            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        arrayFotos.add(new BeanFotos("", imageBitmap, lat, lon));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
```

I am adding the photograph to the array via the constructor, this is the bean:

```
public class BeanFotos {
private Bitmap foto;
private String expediente;
private Double longitud;
private Double latitud;

public BeanFotos(String expediente, Bitmap foto, Double latitud, Double longitud) {
    this.expediente = expediente;
    this.foto = foto;
    this.latitud = latitud;
    this.longitud = longitud;
}

public String getExpediente() {
    return expediente;
}

public void setExpediente(String expediente) {
    this.expediente = expediente;
}

public Bitmap getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(Bitmap foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}

public Double getLatitud() {
    return latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(Double latitud) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
}

public Double getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(Double longitud) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
}
}
```

And this is the adapter:

```
public class FotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<BeanFotos> fotos;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public FotoAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BeanFotos> fotos){
    this.fotos=fotos;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fotos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return fotos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        int bmWidth=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getWidth();
        int bmHeight=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getHeight();
        int ivWidth;
        int ivHeigth;
        int new_width;
        int new_height;
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_layout, null);
        TextView lat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlat);
        TextView lon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlon);
        ImageView foto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        ivWidth=foto.getWidth();
        ivHeigth=foto.getHeight();
        new_width=ivWidth;
        new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
        Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto(), new_width, new_height, true);
        lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
        lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());
        //foto.setImageBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto().getDrawingCache());
        foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

The layout used in the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/lon"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/lat"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textlon"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textlat"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textlon"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

This way, when I am resizing the image to fit in the ImageView, getWidth() ann getHeight() returns 0, so the image is not painted in the ListView.

How could I get the width and height of the ImageView so I could scale the image properly to fit in the ImageView?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this formula:

```
private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    float density = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}
```

And since I know the size of the ImageView in dos, the image its shown ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting image height width ZERO because you are fetching before applying a bitmap to a ImageView

```html
 int bmWidth=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getWidth();
        int bmHeight=fotos.get(position).getFoto().getHeight();
        int ivWidth;
        int ivHeigth;
        int new_width;
        int new_height;
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_layout, null);
        TextView lat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlat);
        TextView lon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlon);
        ImageView foto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        ivWidth=foto.getWidth();
        ivHeigth=foto.getHeight();
        new_width=ivWidth;
        new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
        Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto(), new_width, new_height, true);
        lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
        lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());
        //foto.setImageBitmap(fotos.get(position).getFoto().getDrawingCache());
        foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);
```

In this code first of you need to fetch bitmap height widht **or** first  apply bitmap to imageview then get its height width then resize it.

because when you fetch its height width, Imageview is empty so you will get 0.
I hope it will work...